# How give parameters to ExtJS controller from Ext.application

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, extjs, controller

Actually I'm creating my first ExtJS 4 MVC application. Following the application guide from documentation, I initialize my controller like that :

```
Ext.application({
name: 'RateManagement',

appFolder: 'softcom',

context: null,

constructor: function(context) {
    this.context = context;
},

launch: function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
        layout: 'fit',
        renderTo: 'rate-management',
        items: [
            {
                xtype : 'ratelist'
            },
            {
                xtype : 'rateedit'
            }
        ]
    });
},

controllers: [
              'Rate'
          ],
```

});

But for future ajax call, my controller need to know the ajaxUrl which is coming from Liferay 6. In Liferay, I can get URL like that :

```
<portlet:resourceURL var="listRates" escapeXml="false" id="listRates"></portlet:resourceURL>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var rateContext = {
        contextPath: '<%=request.getContextPath()%>',
        listRatesUrl : '${listRates}',
        strings: strings
    };
</script>
```

My idea is to pass the var rateContext to my controller "Rate".

Any Idea?
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Concept of passing variable from app to controller looks wrong to me. Instead I would create getter somewhere in your app config

```
Ext.application({
  // ...

  context: null,
  getContext: function() {
    return this.context;
  },
  constructor: function(context) {
    this.context = context;
  },

  // ...
});
```

And then you can `get` it from controller using:

```
this.application.getContext()
```

But if you would like to use approach of passing variable to controller you always can use
[`yourApp.getController("Rate")`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.app.Application-method-getController) (you can do it in your `lounch` method) in order to access the controller.

Comment: How can i pass context to constructor? Actually constructor method isn't called for me

Comment: @Molecular Man, May `yourApp.getController("Rate")` be called from any place(controller, view, model) in app? And in this question: will `RateManagement.getController("Rate")` return the related controller?